# How can I convert this source code to lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

It consists of a map in the list object. I try to match lists with the same id by comparing them through loop statements. How can I convert to lambda?

```
List<Map<String, String>> combineList = new ArrayList<>(); // Temp List
for(Map titleMap : titleList) { // Name List
   for(Map codeMap : codeList) { // Age List
      if(titleMap.get("ID").equals(codeMap.get("ID"))) { // compare Id
         Map<String,String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
          tempMap.put("ID", titleMap.get("ID"));
          tempMap.put("NAME", titleMap.get("NAME"));
          tempMap.put("AGE", codeMap.get("AGE"));
          combineList.add(tempMap);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't compile.. please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Map tempMap = new Map();` - don't use raw-types, and you can't use an interface like that.

Comment: Also, you put TempMap.id two times which one you want to consider titleMap one or codeMap one?

Comment: I suggest that you stop using maps and create a class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already doing it in efficient manner. So if you want you could change same code to just use `stream().forEach` or if want to use streams more do it as below:

```
titleList.stream()
        .forEach(titleMap ->
            combineList.addAll(
                codeList.stream()
                    .filter(codeMap -> titleMap.get("ID").equals(codeMap.get("ID")))
                    .map(codeMap -> {
                      Map<String, Object> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
                      tempMap.put("ID", titleMap.get("ID"));
                      tempMap.put("NAME", titleMap.get("NAME"));
                      tempMap.put("ID", codeMap.get("ID"));
                      tempMap.put("AGE", codeMap.get("AGE"));
                      return tempMap;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
        );
```

Notice that you have to filter from the codeList each time because your condition is that way. Try using a  class in place of Map to be more efficient, cleaner and effective.